# Add commas every digits in numbers of kable()

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have the dataframe below and I create a kable out of this. How could I add commas between numbers every 3 digits?

```
Descs<-structure(list(Mean = c(NaN, 943330388, NaN, NaN, NaN, 543234645, 
45831420, NaN, 27301292, 160818771), Median = c(NaN, 943330388, 
NaN, NaN, NaN, 543234645, 45831420, NaN, 27301292, 160818771), 
    SD = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MAD = c(NA, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0), MIN = c(NA, 943330388, NA, 
    NA, NA, 543234645, 45831420, NA, 27301292, 160818771), MAX = c(NA, 
    943330388, NA, NA, NA, 543234645, 45831420, NA, 27301292, 
    160818771), VAR = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), RANGE = structure(c(NA, 943330388, NA, NA, NA, 543234645, 
    45831420, NA, 27301292, 160818771, NA, 943330388, NA, NA, 
    NA, 543234645, 45831420, NA, 27301292, 160818771), .Dim = c(10L, 
    2L)), QUANTILES = structure(c(NA, 943330388, NA, NA, NA, 
    543234645, 45831420, NA, 27301292, 160818771, NA, 943330388, 
    NA, NA, NA, 543234645, 45831420, NA, 27301292, 160818771), .Dim = c(10L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("25%", "75%")))), row.names = c("Comedy", 
"Education", "Entertainment", "Film & Animation", "Gaming", "Howto & Style", 
"Music", "People & Blogs", "Science & Technology", "Sports"), class = "data.frame")

library(kableExtra)

kable(Descs) %>%
    kable_styling(
      font_size = 15,
      bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")
    )
```

Comment: Does this works for you i.e. `Descs <- Descs %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ formattable::comma(.x,  big.mark = ",", format = "f", digits = 0)))` adn then use `kable` on that object.  The advantage is that it retains the columns as `numeric` while adding the format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the kable format argument, this avoids mucking around with the data prior to putting into the table.

And if you want to clear up the NAs and NaNs you could add in this line of code: `options(knitr.kable.NA = '')`

```
library(kableExtra)

kable(Descs,
      format.args = list(big.mark = ",")) %>%
  kable_styling(
    font_size = 15,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Nice option about the `format.args` within `kable`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

Descs <- apply(Descs, 2, function(x) prettyNum(x, big.mark = ","))

kable(Descs) %>%
  kable_styling(
    font_size = 15,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed")
  )
```

Output:

[image]